# Disk usage for optimizing a partitioned MySQL-Table

Tags: mysql, optimization, space, disk, partition

I have a large MyISAM table with 3 million rows that has a size of 31 GB due to a 10KB blob in each row. The table has already 30 partitions. I want to optimize the table since I am going to remove rows with some old data and resize the blobs.
My question is about the disk usage while optimzing:

If I do an optimize of the whole table, does MySQL steps through the partitions and optimize only one partionen at a time and thus only need extra space of one small partion? Or do I have to optimize a or few partitions in order not to have so much extra disk space while optimizing.

Comment: probably, [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82532/mysql-optimize-table-for-partitions) will give you an answer, brief explanation; there are __separate__ command for `partition` optimization, so, probably, blatant `optimize table` will reserve space for whole table, not per-partition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimizing only a partition with s size of ~1 GB takes only very fews seconds and I could not see any heavy disk usage.

Answer (score 0):

(My answer assumes InnoDB.  Even if I am overly pessimistic, the 'solution' should work fine for MyISAM.)

For InnoDB, keep in mind the issues of `innodb_file_per_table`.

`OPTIMIZE` will build a copy of the entire table.

Solution:  If you are tight on space, you can optimize one partition at a time by doing

```
ALTER TABLE REORGANIZE PARTITION ...
                ( INTO PARTITION ...  );
```

Yes, you will need to build the `...` for one partition at a time, and execute them one at a time.

(Do not do `OPTIMIZE PARTITION`, that will optimize the entire table.)

Would you like to elaborate on what your table is like?  I may want to talk you out of partitioning or talk you into a different way of partitioning.